# Stack trace of form function inside twig template in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem that a variable gets rounded up to 3 decimals after the form function is run on the view object. Literally before form: 1.222666 after form(when rendered) 1.223
So basically I need to know what else is happening inside of form function to locate the code that does this rounding up, I was thinking of doing stack trace of it. But how can I achieve that?
Advice on any other way to find out what is happening inside of form function is more than welcome. Symfony used is 2.6.8

EDIT: To make things more clear.
The view in question is built inside of controller, when going through the steps of it there is no sign of any rounding or number format function. By doing dump() on every individual step I have found that only after rendering this change happens. However in twig file there is only

```
{{ form(productViewObject) }}
```

What I want to do is stack trace on all the actions happening inside of form, so I can locate the piece of code that does the rounding. I am not deeply familiar with Symfony but it seems that there is some kind of event or hook, something that is connected to this form function and performs the change. That is what I want to do.

Comment: An IDE + xdebug so you can set breakpoints and step through the code execution to watch what happens.   There is also looking up and reading the source code for the function that is changing your value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/round.html) **twig round:**

```
{{ 42.55|round }}
{# outputs 43 #}

{{ 42.55|round(1, 'floor') }}
{# outputs 42.5 #}
```

Comment: In my twig file there is no use of such function, I need to locate where it actually happens.

Comment: Are you using `Symfony2`?